# #OpsHub #visual-studio-online Migration failure,

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

How can I fix this error so that the migration completes please?

OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. GetAndDownloadFile :The server returned content type text/html; charset=UTF-8, which is not supported.

Retrys all seem to fail at same changeset ID 371

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you try a 'Get Specific Version' in your source control explorer for this changeset and try to download the particular changeset to a temporary location. Is that activity throwing any error?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. I did Get Specific Version on the change set which contains a .zip file and got same error:- The server returned content type text/html; charset=UTF-8, which is not supported.  I do not know how to overcome this error. I have not seen it during several years working on the same project. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your on-premises TFS version, the issue could be in your TFS Data Cache (on the machine where TFS is deployed) or configuration of Visual Studio or even corruption of data.

This (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3c9ab89-17b0-45b1-bf70-4c338ae6b523/the-server-returned-content-type-texthtml-charsetutf8-which-is-not-supported?forum=tfsgeneral) thread might be referred to, for a possible solution. Which suggests the user to clear his cache.

In any case, it might be a good idea to contact Microsoft Support or try posting on Social MSDN.

Comment: Microsoft seem unable to correct this bug. I tried deleting the offending file from the project so that the offending changeset was not used. I started a new migration but that failed as the unused changeset was still accessed.

Comment: This means thirty years of code is locked up because of one file and a bug in TFS 2010. Maybe you can suggest an alternative approach, otherwise I will just give up on Microsoft forever. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey Edward, in an upcoming version of our migration utility. We are introducing a feature which would allow you to skip particular changeset(s). Maybe you could leverage that for your migration. However, since all changes of that changeset would be skipped. How it affects your subsequent changeset history has to be analyzed. But we'll keep you updated about the date of our next release.

Comment: Thank you Opshub. Any estimate on release date?

Comment: Hi Edwards, By our current plan, the release is scheduled for last week of March. We'll give you a heads up on this thread once it is out.