# Migration Failure - Skip Changeset

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am having the same issue discussed here:
[#OpsHub #visual-studio-online Migration failure,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709988/opshub-visual-studio-online-migration-failure)

In the comments Opshub says they are going to add a feature that allows us to skip changesets in March 2015.  Has this feature been added yet?  I am running v1.3.1.000 and I don't see such feature in the UI.

Comment: Neither do I. Can't find the feature in Opshub. By the way, can you share the detailed migration logs so we can check what's the root cause leads to migration fail.

Comment: There is a new version 2.0.0.000 release on 11/18, you may try with it to see if this feature has been added.

Comment: I have updated to version 2 and encountered the same issue.  I see no new features in the free version of the utility.  I also do not see any features in the premium version that would help work around this issue.

Comment: @Vicky Here is a excerpt from the log
http://pastebin.com/Z9jcUYh2
Let me know if there is something else you need.

Comment: Skipping changeset feature will be available with our paid offerings. Please reach out us at sales@opshub.com for more details.